# how to define node_acl public accessible resources

Tags: node.js, express, node-acl

guys am having a hard time wiht node_Acl.

i have adedd.

```
acl.allow('guest',['/docs/'],['show']);

app.use(acl.middleware);
```

but its shows me User is not authorized. when accessing

```
acl.addUserRoles('api_user', 'business',function(err) {

  if(!err) {
    log.debug("api_user with business role created");
  }
});


acl.addUserRoles('helpdesk', 'helpdesk',function(err) {

  if(!err) {
    log.debug("helpdesk with helpdesk role created");
  }
});

acl.userRoles( 'admin', function(err, roles) {
log.debug(roles);
});

acl.roleUsers( 'business', function(err, users){

  log.debug(users);
});

acl.hasRole( 'admin', 'business', function(err, hasRole) {
log.debug("admin user hasRole business =>"+hasRole);
});

acl.allow('admin', ['/api/hellobill/v1/hello'], ['get'], function(err) {
  console.log("EROOR"+err);
});

acl.allow([
        {
            roles: ['guest'],
            allows: [
                { resources: '/docs/', permissions: 'get' }
            ],
        }
    ]);


acl.allow('guest', '/docs/', ['get','put', 'delete']);


app.get('/docs/', acl.middleware(), function (req, res) {
        console.log(req);
    });

acl.allow('public', ['/', '/docs/', '/api-docs/'], 'view');

acl.whatResources('public',function(err,resources){
      console.log(resources);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain without seeing the rest of your code, but I'm going to guess that the user in question has not been granted the 'guest' role, or else there is no active user when you hit that resource. As far as I can tell, with that library you have to explicitly grant any roles you refer to, there's no magic in the role names that imply behavior.

So at some point you'd have to do `acl.addUserRoles(theUser, "guest")` for it to work.

If you want a resource that is simply not protected, truly public, then I would recommend only mounting the middleware on the routes that should be protected, eg:

`app.use('/private', acl.middleware())`

/* Update */

OK, and what user is trying to access the resource and getting the error?

I don't think it's related, but you also don't need the slashes in your resource. So you can do `acl.allow('guest', 'docs', ['get','put', 'delete']);`

Comment: Thanks for the edits; I can never get formatting to work right from my iphone.

Comment: btw am using swagger middleware ?